# Prove that limit doesnot exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f$ be a function defined as follows.
$$f(x)= \cases{
x & if $x$ is irrational \\
1-x & if $x$ is rational}$$

Using the basic definitions of limits show that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) $ does not exist, where $a\neq \frac{1}{2}$.

I tried to find the answer using contradiction.
I assumed that limit exist and tried to proceed. I cant find the answer.
Plz help.

Comment: Instead of actual proof, you can try looking at it in a logical way. Except the number $1\over 2$, where both $x$ and $1-x$ have the same value, taking any number $a$, you cannot definitely say whether the number directly preceding it is rational or irrational. (You can't even get the number). Hence the limit is not defined at the point. 
(Might be useful : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function )

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\;a\neq\frac12\;$ , and let $\;\{x_n\}\subset\Bbb Q\;,\;\;\{y_n\}\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\;$ be two sequences such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=a$$

Thus, we get that

$$\begin{cases}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n=a\\{}\\\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(y_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (1-y_n)=1-a\end{cases}$$

observe that $\;a=1-a\iff a=\frac12\;$ , so that both limits above are different and thus Heine's definition of limit of $\;\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)\;$  isn't fulfilled.

Comment: I have to get the answer from basic definitions of limits without using any other theorems.

Comment: This is as basic as it gets **after** the $\;\epsilon-\delta\;$ definitions ...If you wanted this you should probably add it to your question.